# database --> osm2po --> gph

Tags: osm2po

I know osm2po is great for getting an osm file into a database.  I used it to load an entire country in a country_2po_4pgr table.

What I would like to do is then reverse the process, to be able generate an osm2po .gph file based on an SQL query to country_2po_4pgr of a certain polygon inside the country.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

no, currently it is not possible. But if I understood you correctly you are going to clip a region from a country extract. If you are not going to modify the country_2po_4pgr there is a parameter for this purpose.

e.g.: `joinFilter.boundings=53.5,10.0,53.6,10.1,53.5,10.1,53.5,10.0`

For a detailed explanation please have a look into the `osm2po.config` file